# Is it always true that "If $p$ is a real polynomial such that its derivative is positive all over the real line, then it is of degree odd."?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I tried with some examples to verify that **"If $p$ is of even degree, then $p'(x)$ is less than zero for some number $x$** (choosing large enough positive $y$ and $x=-y$ when leading coefficient is positive).
But I still now struggles to prove this statement.
Can anyone give me some idea to prove this?

Comment: Hint:  if $p(x)$ has even degree then $p'(x)$ has odd degree.  Now just argue that any odd degree polynomial must go to $-\infty$ either as $x\to \infty$ or as $x\to -\infty$ depending on the sign of the lead term.

Comment: Though this argument is visibly clear, I think it is not obvious. But I confine myself to find an $x$ with $q(x)<0$, where $q$ is odd degree polynomial. And I proved it here in my Answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $p$ is of even degree, then $p'$ is of odd degree and my question is proved once we prove the following:

> If $q(x)=a_0+a_1 x+\dotso +a_n x^n$ is a polynomial of odd degree, then $q(x)<0$ for some real $x$.

For the case where $a_0,~\dotso ,~a_{n-1}$ are all zero, $q(x)=a_n x^n$ and $q(-1)<0$ if $a_n>0$ and $q(1)<0$ if $a_n<0$. So, assume that $a_0,~\dotso ,~a_{n-1}$ are not all zero.

Now, suppose $a_n>0$. Then $q(x)<0$ for some $x<0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a_0+a_1 x+\dotso +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}<-a_n x^n$ for some $x<0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $-\frac{1}{a_n}[\frac{a_0}{x^n}+\dotso +\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}]<0$ for some $x<0$.

We here note that $lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=0$, where $f(x)$ is left hand side of the above. This means that the above is true for some $x<0$.

Suppose $a_n<0$. Then proceed as in the above with $x>0$ and finally we get an $x>0$ such that $q(x)<0$ using the fact that $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$.